# const correctness and member reference

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following class:

```
class DataBuilder
{
public:
    DataBuilder(Data& data): data_(data){}

    //Fun modify data_, uses private methods
    void Fun(std::string name, int id) //const ?
    { 
        //calculate newInfo based on params (uses private methods)
        auto& info = data_.GetInfo();
        info = newInfo;
    }
private:
    //some private methods
    Data& data_;
};
```

Theoretically **Fun** can be **const** but I wonder if it is correct (logical constness) ?

**Edit1** I added a very simplified Fun implementation.
**Edit2** Data has two GetInfo overloads:

```
Info& Data::GetInfo();
const Info& Data::GetInfo() const;
```

Comment: It depends what `Fun` does exactly.

Comment: Don't you get a compile error when trying to call a non const method from a const method?? Private or not.

Comment: Yes, I get errors - if Fun is const then every private method which it calls also has to be const

Comment: Please see Edit

Comment: @Irbis If GetInfo is not const, the compiler will throw an error, since it migth change your private member data_. This is desired behavior.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: schorsch312, there is no compiler error when Fun is const

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` in this context means "does not modify the object", which is enforced by treating the implicit `this` as pointer-to-const. For this reason it is common to see overloads like

```
Data       & getData();
Data const & getData() const;
```

This preserves the `const`ness of the calling context, and allows for modifying the `Data` when called in a non-const context.

In your case, you don't have a `Info & Data::getInfo const;` (which would be rather suspect, where does const `Data` get a non-const `Info` from?) `Fun` is modifying the `data_` member of `DataBuilder`.

Aside:
I would write the assignment as `data.GetInfo() = newInfo;`

Comment: So it doesn't matter that the member (Data&) is reference to the object which is defined outside DataBuilder class ?

Comment: But when Fun is const and a member is Data&  then Fun can call non-const Data methods. Why there is no compiler error ?

Comment: I was wrong about references, they behave like pointers (apart from the re-pointing). Yes, you can modify `data_` in `DataBuilder::Fun() const`.

Comment: So Fun should be declared as const (if compiler doesn't complain) or not ? It modify an object but Data is defined outside DataBuilder - and this confuse me.

Comment: Is `Data` conceptually part of the `DataBuilder`? How does the `DataBuilder` get it's `data_`? From the name I'm surprised it's a reference member.

Answer (score 2):

`Fun` is manipulating data. So it *should* not be able to be declared `const`. The fact that you *are* able to do that is that apparently, `data.GetInfo` is declared `const`, yet returns a reference through which you can manipulate it's internal state. That's bad programming.

So no, this is not correct. Even in theory, `Fun` should not be `const` because it is not. It is manipulating internal state. The fact that it *could* be is due to bad coding. Fix that. `const`-correctness is something that cannot be done halfheartedly. You do it, or you don't.